# Parameter name in object when its created

Tags: javascript

I want to get parameter name when a function applied as new. I have search but i couldn't find what i am exactly looking.

Here is a sample;

```
var myobject = function(){
    /*I need "param" in here as string*/
}

var param = new myobject();
```

thanks for any idea or referance without any library.

the original case code is:

```
var selectQueue = [];
var queue = function(data){
    this.defaults = {
        name: "base",
        type: "fifo"
    }
    this.availableTypes = ["fifo","lifo","random"];
    if(!data){data = {};}
    for(param in this.defaults){
        if(!data[param]){
            data[param] = this.defaults[param];
        }
    }

    /*this is what i want to do with dynamic name*/
    selectQueue.push({
        a:this
    });

}

var a = new queue();
```

Comment: I couldn't understand why someone gives my question a minor point. Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Getting the name of a parameter is not really a thing in js, nor would it be good practise. I do not understand what you would want to do with it, but just define a string `var paramString = "param"`

Comment: You could pass in variable name as a strong, but there really isn't a way to get it automatically. Why do you need this?

Comment: i want to get that for triggering an event when all created async queue objects finished it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not really possible in JS, but a possible workaround is to send the name you want to the constructor, such as:

```
var selectQueue = [];
var queue = function(data, name){
    this.defaults = {
        name: "base",
        type: "fifo"
    }
    this.availableTypes = ["fifo","lifo","random"];
    if(!data){data = {};}
    for(param in this.defaults){
        if(!data[param]){
            data[param] = this.defaults[param];
        }
    }

    var o = {};
    o[name] = this;
    selectQueue.push(o);
}

var a = new queue(data, 'a');
```

Another possibility is to keep track of the current index of `selectQueue`.

Answer (score -2):

The object has properties and this is the syntax.

```
var myObject = function(){
    name: "your name",
    age: 19,
    hobby: "football"
}

var param = myObject.name;
```

That is the way you define a property.

Comment: I dont want to define a property.

Comment: in that case i think you need to define a constructor

Comment: var myObject = function(){
           name: "your name",
           age: 19,
           hobby: "football"
        }

        myObject.name = "your name";

Comment: I think I couldn't explain my need clearly, i need the name of parameter inside the function so i can stack names of params in a global array.

Comment: @Yya09 did you try running any of the code samples you are supplying? If the question is unclear, clarify it using comments, not botched answers.